# Is there a way to set background from android:drawable programatically?

Tags: java, android, background, drawable

Well I know that this can be done in xml this way

```
android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_dropdown_dark_frame"
```

this line above is from my mind so it can have some errors, but basically is that way. Now how can I do the same thing but programatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this (from a View subclass):

```
setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.editbox_dropdown_dark_frame);
```

If you have a reference to the view (say, from `findViewById`), you can do the same thing:

```
View v = . . .;
v.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.editbox_dropdown_dark_frame);
```

If you like, you can retrieve the `Drawable` itself directly:

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(
    android.R.drawable.editbox_dropdown_dark_frame);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/background_tv"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

---

```
TextView toChange = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.background_tv);
toChange.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.editbox_dropdown_dark_frame);
```